# Strange clock() behaviour

Tags: c, time, clock

Could someone explain this clock() (time_h) behaviour:

```
clock_t start, stop;
long i;
double t = 0.;
for(i = 0; i < 10e7; i++){
    start = clock();
    //nothing
    stop = clock();
    t = t + (double)(stop - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
printf("t: %fs\n", t);
```

Output:

```
t: 12.883712s
```

I suppose that the reason could be the accumulation of small t values caused by clock() error. Is there a way to deal with that?

Update: Just to explain 'real world' situation, because there are a lots of suggestions. *//nothing* is a block of code which time interval is very small (probably in nanoscale) and instead of one loop there are few of them which are also hard to measure.

Comment: why do you expect that start and stop are equal ? calling "clock()" and copying the value to the varaible isn't "//nothing" ;)

Comment: How long does it take to execute your program (use a *real* wall clock)?

Comment: What is the expected value? Certainly not zero, there's a non-zero probability of the clock going up between two measurements.

Comment: Where's `#include <time.h>`?  Without that, the return value from `clock()` will be truncated to a signed `int` value.

Comment: @Matsmath clock() execution affect total time, so there is no point to measure program time in total.

Comment: @Tommylee2k I don't! But if the 'error' is in that scale, how to deal with this and measure time in µs precision?

Comment: `clock()` does not have enough precision to do that. You need a clock that runs faster than  the interval you are trying to time. Alternatively time the entire iteration loop, calling `clock` before and after.

Comment: @WeatherVane In real case, I need to measure only a part of the operations inside a loop and to accumulate it at the end. So, I can't do it with the entire loop. But, you are probably right.

Comment: @zarko: If you want to measure part of a loop, you can try the following: measure 1e8 whole iterations of the loop (let be `A`; then measure 1e8 iterations where you _skip_ the part you want to measure (let be `B`). The time needed for that part is `(A - B) / 1e8`.

Comment: @rodrigo Interesting suggestion, but won't work in my case because B part (block without measuring part) is also a small interval. It could work if B is measurable.

Comment: @zarko: Why not? In my suggestion A and B are actually the total measurement of 1e8 iterations of that small blocks. Those should be measurable even if the code is very small.

Comment: @rodrigo Oh, I got it now! You are right, now I have result very close to solution with Bathsheba's _calibration_. You should post it as an answer!

Comment: @zarko: Ok, I've added an answer below, HTH.

Answer (score 3):

The answer you're getting is reasonable, since the compiler can't optimise out the `clock()` calls and I don't see calls to `clock()` as being particularly cheap.

But your measurement is numerically inaccurate - I think your approach underestimates the total. Try

```
clock_t start, stop;
clock_t total = 0;
for (long/*don't overflow a 16 bit int*/ i = 0; i < 10e7; i++){
    start = clock();
    stop = clock();
    total += stop - start
}
double t = 1.0 * total / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("t: %fs\n", t);
```

instead. That is, perform the division at the end.

You could, in a sense, *calibrate* the overhead using

```
start = clock();
/*ToDo - the real code*/
stop = clock();
control = clock();
/*Time is (stop - start) - (control - stop)*/
```

Comment: You made a few valuable marks, but the result is still the same.

Comment: The _calibration_ could be a good trick, but still there is a problem with inaccuracy for a small time intervals. Sims that clock_gettime() could with its nanoprecision could deal with it.

Comment: Note: `i < 10e7` would generate FP code.  Suggest `i < (long)10e7`.  Likely does not change output, but would run faster/as fast.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot measure very short timespans with `clock()` (or for that matter, with any other method unless you use a real-time OS and a lot of care).

Adding up a lot of small measurements is not a good idea, because granularity problems may accumulate. It is far better to measure the big loop and divide by the number of iterations:

```
clock_t start, stop;
long i, num_iter = 1e8;
start = clock();
for(i = 0; i < num_iter; i++){
    //whatever
}
stop = clock();
t = (double)(stop - start) / num_iter / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("t: %fs\n", t);
```

If you feel that the time of `//whatever` is too short, just increate the number of iterations!

But what if the loop code has two parts: one to prepare the data, another one is the real code you want to measure? ...and you cannot run the real code without the preparation phase. Or simply, what if the code I want to measure is very short and the loop overhead is too significant?

Then one way to do it is to run the measurement twice, one of them bypassing the to-be-measured code, and then calculate the difference:

```
clock_t start, time1, time2;
long i, num_iter = 1e8;
double t;

start = clock();
for(i = 0; i < num_iter; i++){
    prepare_algoritm();
}
time1 = clock() - start;

start = clock();
for(i = 0; i < num_iter; i++){
    prepare_algoritm();
    run_algorith();
}
time2 = clock() - start;

t = (double)(time2 - time1) / num_iter / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; 
printf("run_algorithm time: %fs\n", t);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following modification of your program:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[]) {
  clock_t start, stop;
  int i;
  double t = 0.;
  int n = atoi(argv[1]);
  int cnt = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    start = clock();
    //nothing
    stop = clock();
    if ( start != stop) {
      printf( "%d %d\n", start, stop);
      cnt++;
    }
    t = t + (double)(stop - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  }
  printf("t: %gs %g %d\n", t, t/n, cnt);
  return 0;
}
```

And the output for two runs

```
$ ./a.out 1000000
30000 40000
70000 80000
90000 100000
110000 120000
170000 180000
180000 190000
220000 230000
230000 240000
240000 250000
250000 260000
260000 270000
270000 280000
t: 0.12s 1.2e-07 12

$ ./a.out 100000
t: 0s 0 0
```

This shows that you are getting non-zero values because when you run the loop enough times the `start` and `end` values are different because occasionally one runs right before the `clock` time is about to change and so the second call returns a different value. When this happens `t` will increase.

Comment: Thx. So, those not-zero values are different enough that it produce huge error in this scale (12s for 10e7 e.g.). Is that your point?

Comment: @zarko Yes, the difference in `stop - start` is 10000, when divided by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` this becomes 0.01. Note in the example above there are 12 times `stop` and `start` are not equal and the measured time is 0.12 (12*0.01). It either need to measure the time before and after the loop or use a more accurate time than `clock()`, maybe `clock_gettime()`?

Comment: It seems that clock_gettime() provides nanoseconds resolution. I'll try it. Thx.